# How do I decrypt in php something aes encrypted with c#

Tags: c#, php, aes

A partner is using c# to encrypt 12 digit numbers to a database, I need to decode these values on a unix server ideally using php 5.6 but php 7.2, perl 5.16 or python 3.6 are all available.

I've started with example 2 of the php openssl-encrypt manual which gets me something which will encode/decode test strings successfully, but cannot decode the c# encoded data.

I've also tried the suggestions at https://odan.github.io/2017/08/10/aes-256-encryption-and-decryption-in-php-and-csharp.html without success, presumably because the partner isn't using CBC.

Substituting `$key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret, true), 0, 32);` for the secret in the function calls didn't help.

I've tried all the ciphers supported by openssl-encrypt without success.

The partner has provided their c# code (which appears to be a more or less direct lift from Microsoft sample code):

```cs
public static string EncryptString(string key, string plainText)
 {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] array;
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
        }

        public static string DecryptString(string key, string cipherText)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
                        {
                            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have the following functions at present:

```
function encrypt2($data, $secret, $cipher, $iv)
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher, $secret, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $secret, $as_binary=true);

    return base64_encode($ciphertext_raw);
}

function decrypt2($data, $secret, $cipher, $iv)
{
    $c = base64_decode($data);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($c, $cipher, $secret, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return ($original_plaintext ? $original_plaintext : 'openssl_decrypt failed');
}
```

I can't share partner data because I only have real data but here is an example call to the php functions above the second of which produces results resembling the real data:

```
$data = '123456789012';
$secret = "qwertyuiop12345";
$cipher = "AES-256-ECB";
$iv = "";
$encrypted2 = encrypt2($data, $secret, $cipher, $iv);
$decrypted2 = decrypt2($encrypted2, $secret, $cipher, $iv);
echo "$data > $encrypted2 > $decrypted2\n";
```

Gives:

```
123456789012 > NDdefqxcYZvtjAcvPrQ00A== > 123456789012
```

What changes do I need to make to my php to match the c# code?

Alternatively a solution using perl or python would work.

Update with sample data:

`xyz@gmail.com` encrypted with `b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916` gives `c4Eej4S8G3mclVQJb+qkfQ==`

That's exactly what my code generates.

The live key I've been given is 16 characters long but the example above uses a 32 character string, is something being done to double the length of the original before use?

Comment: _"ideally using php 5.6 but php 7.2, ... are all available."_ - Ideally, you should be using PHP 7.2 since 5.6 isn't supported anymore. You should also post a real example of a string both encrypted and un-encrypted from C#. If not, we can't really test your code without setting up both a C# and a PHP environment, which is a big ask.

Comment: points taken, I've updated with an example that slightly refocuses the question.